# PHP fileToUpload

Tags: php, html

I've traced around many of the forums looking for an answer. Hopefully someone could steer me in the right direction. Or possibly have the answer.

I understand this part

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

I get most of this part.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    echo $imageFileLoc;
    //echo "www.fastersmartereasier.com/noindex/video/test/uploads/".basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

Now if I select the file and hit submit. All works fine.

The problem is, I don't want to have to select the file. I want to launch my HTML page and it upload my files that reside in a folder. Let's call it /Users/Scott/Desktop/exports

Based on the forums I've found, PHP isn't able to do that.

1) is this true?
2) if it isn't how can I use PHP to take files from a defined folder.
3) If it is true, what Methods can I do to achieve the above without using PHP then.

Comment: The reason PHP alone can't do it is that it runs on the server and has no access to your local filesystem...

Answer (score 1):

Is a security feature, the user must select or drop the file into the browser window. If we can set the value dynamically we can steal any file from the user computer.

You can use html5 and drag and drop multiple files at a time, but you can not set the value dynamically using JavaScript.

[Take a look on this link to upload multiples files.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_multiple.asp)

Comment: Thank you, that makes complete sense.

What would you suggest?

I'm trying to automate the last part of my plugin, which exports a video from Adobe After Effects. I can define it's location to export to, but I can't just export it to the server.

So once it's finished exporting, I need something to upload it to that folder from /Users/Scott/Desktop/exports.

Can I achieve this using via ftp in anyway?

Once it's on my server, the PHP script on my server then uploads it to Dailymotion (This part is working aswell)

So it's just the middle part of getting it on my server.

Comment: Can you export it to a share on the server(windows) or mount on mac/linux? Also you can create a scrip to monitor the folder for changes and upload everything to the server.

Comment: That's a good shout, I didn't think about that. I'll give the mount a go before I look at a script file on my MAC.